# Can a Vue.js build (bundle) be used in another website?

Tags: vue.js, build, web-applications

Let's say we build a small quiz app in **Vue3.js**, nothing fancy, few questions, and on the last route a submit button (which will post answers to a route). After **the build**, can we use this app on **another website** (static, or dynamic, with a PHP backend ), **and how**?